# Indentations in Algorithm floats in LYX

Tags: lyx, indentation, algorithms

I am using LYX and I'm trying to enter algorithms in an algorithm float.
Is there a way to have indentation?

Answer (score 2):

Inside the LyX environment, you can't show indentation. Moreover, the LyX interface for algorithms is very limited under the `algorithm2e` module (Document > Settings... > Modules > Algorithm2e).

You can use the ERTs `\Indp` and `\Indm` to add - or `p`lus - indentation and remove - or `m`inus indentation:

[image]

[image]